# Brand new to Haskell, why does this function loop forever?

Tags: haskell

**Context:** I am less than a week into figuring Haskell out, I'm enjoying myself so far, but this one is stumping me. This seems the simplest example that demonstrates my problem:

I have the following Type defined.

```
data AnInteger = A Integer
instance Eq AnInteger where
  a == a' = a == a'
```

But when I try to use it

[image: Screenshot of ghci infinite looping]

I get what appears to be an infinite loop. What's going on here that I'm not getting?

How can I correct the syntax to provide the desired output of **True**?

Comment: It's like saying `main = main`. You've defined equality as a recursive call to itself.

Comment: In the future, please post the image text, not the image. Most terminals will let cut&paste from them in some way. Images containing text are frowned upon here on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're defining the `==` operator by saying that `a` is equal to `a'` iff `a` is equal to `a'`. Logically this is a tautology.

In terms of program logic it's an infinite loop, as applying the `==` function to two arguments will apply it again to those same arguments, infinitely.

What you probably intended to do was to use `==` to compare the integers wrapped in your `AnInteger`s, rather than the `AnInteger`s themselves. To do this, you'll first need to use pattern matching to unwrap them like this:

```
(A a) == (A a') = a == a'
```